# How do I know which repository the installed Chart belongs to

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have many helm repositories in my kubernetes,
And I installed a lot of charts,
So How do I know which repository the installed Chart belongs to?
For example:

```
$> helm repo list
  NAME            URL
  lucy-dev        https://harbor.mydomain.net/chartrepo/lucy-dev
  lucy-prod       https://harbor.mydomain.net/chartrepo/lucy-prod

$> helm ls -n msgbox-lucy -o yaml
- app_version: "1.0"
  chart: msgbox-lucy-8.27.3
  name: msgbox-lucy
  namespace: msgbox-lucy
  revision: "48"
  status: deployed
  updated: 2022-04-19 08:11:16.761059067 +0000 UTC
```

I can't use `helm show` because:

```
$> helm show all msgbox-lucy -n msgbox-lucy --debug
show.go:195: [debug] Original chart version: ""
Error: non-absolute URLs should be in form of repo_name/path_to_chart, got: msgbox-lucy
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you're guaranteed to get the info you're looking for, however we can try.

Find the latest Helm secret for your Helm release.

```
kubectl get secret -n msgbox-lucy
```

Yours might look something like this:

```
sh.helm.release.v1.msgbox-lucy.v5
```

and run this command to view the chart's metadata:

```
SECRET_NAME="sh.helm.release.v1.msgbox-lucy.v5"

kubectl get secret $SECRET_NAME -o json | jq .data.release \
  | tr -d '"' | base64 -d | base64 -d | gzip -d \
  | jq '.chart.metadata'
```

The metadata should hopefully show you 2 things you're looking for. The chart name will be under the `name` field. The chart repository URL might be under `sources`.

I say "might" because the chart developer should have added it there, but they might not have.

Then you can match the URL to your repo alias.

---

If it's not included in the metadata, you're probably out of luck for now.

There is an open Github issue about exactly this feature you're wanting:

https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4256

And an open PR that adds that feature:

https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/10369

And an open PR to add a HIP (Helm Improvement Proposal) for adding that feature:

https://github.com/helm/community/pull/224

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried and luck wasn't on my side, I will wait final solution

Answer (score 0):

You can run `helm search repo <keyword>`

This will search for the keyword `msgbox-lucy` in all your available repos and list results.

```
helm search repo msgbox-lucy
```

Official Doc : https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_search_repo/